# Generating names for Urls with same Host .net

Tags: .net, winforms, generator

I have a bug generating names for urls i automatically import to my app
For example, currently i generate url names by extracting the host name like this

```
www.example.com/some-dir/page.htm  becomes example.com
```

But i get a funny bug when i have urls such as these

```
www.example.com/some-dir/page.htm
www.example.com/another-dir/page.htm
www.example.com/yet-another-dir/another-page.htm
```

so currently i try to fix by appending a number to the name like this

```
www.example.com/some-dir/page.htm  = example.com
www.example.com/another-dir/page.htm  = example.com1
www.example.com/yet-another-dir/another-page.htm  = example.com2
```

but i think there would probably be a better way, an example i think are these

```
www.example.com/some-dir/page.htm  = example.com
www.example.com/another-dir/page.htm  = example1.com
www.example.com/yet-another-dir/another-page.htm  = example2.com
```

but can anyone suggest anything better or how i can do this last variation in code?

thanks

Comment: You start by talking about **generating** URLs and then you talk about **extracting** the domain name, so.. what's the question?

Comment: i made some edits, but am talking about generating names for urls

Comment: What's the motive? You need unique names for a dictionary? (solved with GUIDs for example), You need unique display-names?, If you get the exact same URL twice would you like to have the same name or a different one?

Comment: i need unique display-names for urls with the same host but different absoluteURi or path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary for mapping a domain name to an integer counter, e.g.:
`Dictionary<string, int> m_domainNameToCounterMap`

Then, maintain your counter by extracting the domain name and matching up against the dictionary:

```
private static void DomainNameTest()
{
    Dictionary<string, int> m_domainNameToCounterMap;

    string domainName;
    if ( !m_domainNameToCounterMap.ContainsKey( domainName ) )
    {
        m_domainNameToCounterMap.Add( domainName, 1 ); // Initial counter
    }

    int domainCounter = m_domainNameToCounterMap[ domainName ];

    // Do some smart naming convention
    Regex re = new Regex("(.*)(\.[^\.]+)$");
    Match m = re.Match(domainName);
    if ( m.Success )
    {
        domainName = string.Format( "{0}{1}{2}", m.Groups[1], domainCounter, m.Groups[2] );
    }

    // Inc. counter for next time
    m_domainNameToCounterMap[ domainName ] = m_domainNameToCounterMap[ domainName ] + 1;
}
```

You add the counter just before the last .something with a little help from regular expressions.

(*) Note: I didn't compile the code so it might not work out of the box, but you get the general idea.